# Find Method Arguments of annotated Method using Java Annotation Processor?

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

I have the following annotation:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface MyAnn {
}
```

and a method annotated with `@MyAnn`:

```
  @MyAnn
  Object myMehtod(Object x) {
  ...
  }
```

Using a Java annotation processor I get the annotated element as:

```
Element annotatedElement // = myMehtod
```

1. **How do I get the return type of this method?**
2. **How do I get the arguments of this method?**
3. **How do I get the name of the arguments of this method?**

Answer (score 7):

Here is my solution:

```
ExecutableType executableType = (ExecutableType)annotatedElement.asType();
List<? extends TypeMirror> parameters = executableType.getParameterTypes();
TypeMirror param1 = parameters.get(0);
DeclaredType declaredType = (DeclaredType)param1;
List<? extends AnnotationMirror> anns = ((TypeElement)declaredType.asElement()).getAnnotationMirrors( );
```

Comment: `ExecutableType executableType = (ExecutableType)annotatedElement.asType();` is causing me compiler errors. Types are not compatible.

Comment: @Samuel That means the thing with the annotation is not a method. Perhaps you've accidentally annotated the return type instead? That would explain the problems you encountered.

Comment: you are supposed to cast the element, not the type: `(ExecutableElement)annotatedElement`

Answer (score 4):

```
ExecutableElement method = ...
```

You can get the return type of the method with

```
TypeMirror returnType = mehod.asType()
```

You can get the arguments of the method with

```
List<? extends VariableElement> parameters = method.getParameters();
```

You can get the name of the parameter with

```
parameters.forEach(p -> {
            String name = p.getSimpleName().toString();
            TypeMirror type = p.asType();
   });
```

Comment: Hi, I always get "arg0" as name for my parameter. What am I missing ?

Comment: One has to add -parameters option to javac when compiling the classes to get parameters names added to metadata for reflection.